# Python（openpyxl）にてexcelの任意の値を貼り付け方法

Tags: python, python3

Pythonで`Book1.xlsx`から1行ずつ値を取得します。
行を取得後、D列`Book2.xlsx`へ貼り付けます。

`Book1.xlsx`

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6月6日 | アメリカ | 15 |
| 6月7日 | 日本 | 35 |
| 6月8日 | スペイン | 45 |

```
A,B,C
6月6日,アメリカ,15
6月7日,日本,35
6月8日,スペイン,45
```

`Book2.xlsx`
貼り付けたいエクセルのはヘッダーがないエクセルなので、openpyxlを使っています。
また行番号もないので、B列に入っている日付をキーにしてD列に値を貼り付けたいです。

| TEST_DATA |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | A | B | C |
|  | 6月4日 | カナダ | 1 |
|  | 6月5日 | イギリス | 109 |
|  | 6月6日 | アメリカ |  |
|  | 6月7日 | 日本 |  |
|  | 6月8日 | スペイン |  |

```
TEST_DATA,,,,
,A,B,C,
,6月4日,カナダ,1
,6月5日,イギリス,109
,6月6日,アメリカ,
,6月7日,日本,
,6月8日,スペイン,
```

実現したい内容
Book1.xlsxのC列からBook2.xlsxのD列に値を貼り付けたいです。
ただA列日付はシリアル値になっていますので、現在は下記のコードで行っています。

`Book2.xlsx`

| TEST_DATA |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | A | B | C |
|  | 6月4日 | カナダ | 1 |
|  | 6月5日 | イギリス | 109 |
|  | 6月6日 | アメリカ | 15 |
|  | 6月7日 | 日本 | 35 |
|  | 6月8日 | スペイン | 45 |

現在は下記の方法で行っていますが、毎回手動で値を変更しいますので
全自動で`Book1.xlsx`から範囲を読み込み`Book2.xlsx`へ貼り付け可能でしょうか。

実現する方法がありましたら、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

お手数ですが、よろしくお願い致します。

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
#ファイル名
Book1=r"C:\Users\test\Desktop\Book1.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(Book1)
#シート指定
ws = wb['Sheet1']

#Book1の２行目を読み込み　
for row in ws.iter_cols():
    for cell in row:
        if cell.row == 2:
            print(cell.value)

#出力結果
# 44718
# アメリカ
# 15

#ファイル名
Book2=r"C:\Users\test\Desktop\Book2.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(Book2)
#シート指定
ws = wb['Sheet1']

#貼り付ける際にキーを基準にしたい列
target_col = "B"
#貼り付ける列
next_col = "D"

#シリアル値　2022/6/6
#日付をヒットする文字
target_string = "44718" 

#1行ずつ読み込み該当のE列エクセルへ貼り付け
for row in range(2, ws.max_row+1):
    if target_string in str(ws[f"{target_col}{row}"].value):
        ws[f"{next_col}{row}"] = 15

#ファイル保存       
wb.save(Book2)
```

Comment: `Book1.xlsx`の`A`,`B`,`C`や`Book2.xlsx`の`TEST_DATA`など実際の元データがどうなっているのかいまいちイメージしにくい気がします。それぞれをCSVにしたらどうなっているかを追記してもらうと良いかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。csvのBook1とBook2を追加致しました。お手隙の際にご確認をお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「貼り付けたいエクセルのはヘッダーがないエクセルなので、openpyxlを使っています。」と書かれていますが、`header=None`を指定すれば`pandas`の`read_excel()`でも問題無く読めます。
書き込む際も`to_excel()`で`index=False`,`header=False`を指定すれば良いでしょう。

以下のようにすれば少ない処理で出来ます。
ファイルのパス指定や`Book2.xlsx`の列名、列番号等はそれぞれ相応しいものに変えてください。

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('Book2.xlsx', header=None, names=['Title','A','B','C'])

for i, e in df1.iterrows():
    df2.iat[(df2.index[(df2.A == e.A)].tolist()[0]), 3] = e.C

df2.to_excel('Book2.xlsx', index=False, header=False)
```

---

「ただ日付はシリアル値44716として保存されます。pandasで変換可能でしょうか。」に関して

一応以下の記事を応用すれば`pandas`で日付シリアル値を変換出来そうですが、これを実際のDataFrameにどう適用するかでとても複雑になりそうです。
[Date serial number and date need to convert in date format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58191555/9014308)

> base on my experience the origin in Excel is December 30, 1899.

> ```
> s1=pd.to_datetime(pd.to_numeric(df.date,errors='coerce'),errors='coerce',origin='1899-12-30',unit='D')
> ```

なので、質問記事のソースコードと以下の記事を応用して、結果のExcelファイルに対して`openpyxl`で書式設定を行うのが簡単だと思われます。
[日時 - PythonでExcel操作【openpyxl - 日付、通貨、日時のフォーマットを制御する】](https://qiita.com/matsuyamasyou/items/36d8d7eaf5a7dcb986a2#%E6%97%A5%E6%99%82)

> ```
> sheet["B1"].number_format = "yyyy年mm月dd日"
> ```

以下のように出来るでしょう。

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('Book2.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

date_col = 'B'
for row in range(2, ws.max_row+1):
    ws[f"{date_col}{row}"].number_format = 'm月d日'

wb.save('Book2.xlsx')
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。pandasの上記の方法でもやってみましたができませんでした。こちらエラーが出ます。もし分かれば教えていけると幸いです。
`df2.iat[(df2.index[(df2.A == e.A)].tolist()[0]), 3] = e.C`
`IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: 失礼しました。D列に値が入っていたのでDのヘッダー追加しましたら貼り付けできました。ただ日付はシリアル値`44716`として保存されます。pandasで変換可能でしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。上記の方法でできました。

Comment: 度々、すいません、まだ理解できない部分がありまて。。` tolist()[0]), 3`の`3`ですが、ABCヘッダーの数でしょうか。

Comment: `3`は列のインデックスです。(`Title`と名付けた)`TEST_DATA`のある列が`0`,以後`A`,`B`,`C`が`1`,`2`,`3`になります。

Comment: なるほどですね、ありがとうございます。